# DELETE ... OUTPUT COUNT(DELETED.*)

Tags: sql, sql-server, output-clause

I want to know how many rows were removed in a certain DELETE operation.

I took [the Microsoft example B](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms177564.aspx) which is

```
DELETE Sales.ShoppingCartItem
OUTPUT DELETED.* 
WHERE ShoppingCartID = 20621;
```

and tried to modify it to return only the `count` of deleted records:

```
DELETE FROM datacache 
OUTPUT COUNT(DELETED.*)
WHERE userId=@id
```

but this throws

```
ExceptionMessage: "Incorrect syntax near '*'."
ExceptionType: "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException"
Message: "Error"
```

So I tried

```
DELETE FROM datacache 
OUTPUT COUNT(DELETED)
WHERE userId=@id
```

which throws

```
ExceptionMessage: "Invalid column name 'DELETED'."
ExceptionType: "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException"
Message: "Error"
```

What did I miss?

Comment: A classic way would be to `SELECT @@ROWCOUNT` which should show you the number of affected rows.

Comment: Please see the link..http://www.sql-server-helper.com/error-messages/msg-158.aspx

Comment: Did any of the answers solved your issue?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just run your query and get the modified rows

```
DELETE 
FROM datacache 
WHERE userId=@id

SELECT @@ROWCOUNT
```

Answer (score 13):

You can not use aggregates in `OUTPUT` clause. You can output any column into table variable instead and count from there:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(id int)

DELETE FROM Sales.ShoppingCartItem
OUTPUT Deleted.ShoppingCartID INTO @t
WHERE ShoppingCartID = 20621;

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @t
```

Answer (score 2):

How about counting the records afterwards?

```
DELETE Sales.ShoppingCartItem
OUTPUT DELETED.ID INTO @DELETEDIDS
WHERE ShoppingCartID = 20621;

SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM @DELETEDIDS;
```

Or, just run the query and use `@@ROWCOUNT`.